# Googles IMPORTXML returns "Imported content is empty" error

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**I'm trying to get the value of the link of the first youtube video that appears after a youtube search** and write it into my google spreadsheet. In order to do this, I am using the in-built `IMPORTXML(url, xml_query)` function. I have copied the full XPath using google chrome and received the following:

```
/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-search/div[1]/ytd-two-column-search-results-renderer/div/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-video-renderer[1]/div[1]/ytd-thumbnail/a/@href
```

I have placed the following code in a spreadsheet cell:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ajfdkla+trailer", "/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-search/div[1]/ytd-two-column-search-results-renderer/div/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-video-renderer[1]/div[1]/ytd-thumbnail/a/@href")
```

and received the following error:

> Imported content is empty.

**How can I write the URL of the first youtube video following a youtube search into my spreadsheet cell.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMPORTXML can't see the DOM shown by Chrome Developer Tools on the **Elements** tab, it can only see the source code returned by the URL, so instead, you should look at the **Sources** tab or easier, right click the page and select **View page source**.

Resources

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)